# Application.Terminate yields access violation error Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, access-violation

The `Application.Terminate()` procedure causes an Access Violation once a dynamic array of `TImage` has been created.

Array (variable length):

```pascal
arrImages: array of TImage;
```

Access violation:

```
Access violation at address 00405D39. Write of address 004680EC
```

Since this only occurs after the dynamic array has been created, I have tried to free all elements in the array (`onTmrImage` is a global variable containing the first element in the array, the elements in the array are each dynamic `TImage` components on the GUI):

```pascal
procedure TfrmTank.procPurgeArray;
var
  I: integer;
begin
  FreeAndNil(onTmrLImage);
  for I := 1 to length(arrImages) do
  begin
    FreeAndNil(arrImages[I]);
  end;

  FreeAndNil(arrImages);

end;
```

And then used `Application.Terminate()` in the `onClick` event of the exit button:

```pascal
procedure TfrmTank.btnExitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  procPurgeArray;
  Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Any idea as to why it is necessary to even do anything to simply exit the application?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. That includes declaration of all variables where you call FreeandNil. You are calling FreeAndNil on dynamic array and you must not do that. Dynamic arrays are not objects and they are automatically managed.

Comment: Also, it seems very likely the `for` loop should go from `0` to `High(ArrImages)` (=`Length(ArrImages) - 1`). (If there are five elements, these are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 -- not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.)

Answer (score 3):

```
freeandnil(arrImages);
```

This is a bug. You must not call `Free` on a dynamic array. You can call `Free` on an object instance. Replace this line of code with `arrImages := nil`.

Dynamic arrays are destroyed automatically because they are managed types.

You also get the array indices wrong when destroying the images. Dynamic arrays are zero-based. Your loop should be:

```
for I := 0 to High(arrImages) do
  arrImages[I].Free;
arrImages := nil;
```

Perhaps the same mistake is present in the code that creates the array.

With all this said, surely this code belongs in a destructor. And one could even argue that it's a little pointless when you are about to do `Application.Terminate`.

Comment: `for I := 1 to length(arrImages) do` is not very good either.

Comment: Potentially off-topic, but I like your new icon, @David.

Comment: hey @David thanks a lot. I do suspect that I have done something to disturb the application.terminate procedure although i am unsure. I was attempting to delete the entire array before terminate since i thought the filled array may be causing the error. Thank you so much for your answer, i have used arrImages:=nil but the error still occurs, so I will run more tests to narrow down the problem area.

Comment: If there are more 1-based instead of 0-based errors in the code that could explain it. There's really nothing more to be said at this question. It has been answered.

Comment: yes it was indeed the problem thanks guys!